# Joining arrays together but across each other

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I have three arrays like so

```
$wages = array("Tom" => "£20", "Mike" => "£5.60", "James" => "12");
$training = array("Tom" => "£2", "James" => "7", "Dean" => "£3.50");
$tax = array("James" => "£1.50", "Kevin" => "£3", "Dean" => "£2");
```

Each array has the wages/training/tax for **every** employee. What I'm trying to do is separate them out so that I can have a single array for each employee. Desired result would be in the format of `employee => (wages, training, tax)`:

```
$array1 = array("Tom" => "£20", "£2", "0");
$array2 = array("Mike" => "£5.60", "0", "0");
$array3 = array("James" => "£12", "£7", "£1.50");
```

The reason I am doing this, is because I want to write the result to a spreadsheet via CSV (`fputcsv`). Now, I have been trying to reorganise like so:

First combing the array to have both key and value the same.

`$combined = array_combine($employeesList, $employeesList);`

`employeesList` only contains the names of the employees as values.

Then looping through this employees array to see if any of the keys exist in the arrays defined above like so:

```
foreach ($employeesList as $employee) {
    if (array_key_exists($employee, $wages))
        $combined[$employee] = array($employee, $wages[$employee]);
    }
}
```

This part works fine. Then I do it for the tax array like so:

```
foreach ($tax as $key => $value) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $combined)) {
        array_push($combined[$key], $value);
}
```

But this fails at the second iteration saying that `array_push` is expecting an array when string is given. Like the arrays above show, not every employee will have a record for every field. So i'm wondering how I can fix this? And/or if there is an alternative route to the one I'm taking. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First extract all of the names

```
$names = array_unique(array_merge(array_keys($wages), array_keys($training), array_keys($tax)));
```

Then iterate over the names to generate the record set

```
$employeeList = [];
foreach ($names AS $name)
    $employeeList[$name] = [@$wages[$name] ?: 0, @$training[$name] ?: 0, @$tax[$name] ?: 0];
```

Note the error suppression with `@` ... this is performed because we don't  care when individual values are missing; a default is provided.

Which will result in a set like the following

```
> var_dump($employeeList);
array(5) {
  ["Tom"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "£20"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "£2"
    [2]=>
    int(0)
  }
  ["Mike"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "£5.60"
    [1]=>
    int(0)
    [2]=>
    int(0)
  }
  ["James"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "12"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "7"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "£1.50"
  }
  ["Kevin"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(0)
    [1]=>
    int(0)
    [2]=>
    string(3) "£3"
  }
  ["Dean"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(0)
    [1]=>
    string(6) "£3.50"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "£2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked for me! Thank you!